# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.serlializer'

Tags: python, reactjs, django, serialization

I've installed Django 3.1.4 and djangorestframework 3.12.2.
I am attempting to run makemigrations for a music website I am building and I keep getting this error in the terminal and haven't been able to figure out what is causing it.

```
    (Django_React) PS C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\music_site> python .\manage.py makemigrations          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\music_site\music_site\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    urlpatterns = [path("admin/", admin.site.urls), path("", include("api.urls"))]
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\music_site\api\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import RoomView
  File "C:\Users\BB_SO\desktop\dev\Django_React\music_site\api\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .serlializer import RoomSerializer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.serlializer'
```

Here my serializer.py file content:

```
from rest_framework import serializer
from .models import Room


class RoomSeralizer(seriarlizers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = (
            "id",
            "code",
            "host",
            "guest_can_pause",
            "vote_to_skip",
            "created_at",
        )
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? I am still very new to coding and am using vscode if that helps at all. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: whats the `serializer` file named? `serlializer.py`? or `serializer.py`?

Comment: The file is named serializers.py.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.serlializer'`. stack trace says something else, there is a typo in the filename

Comment: Thanks for your help! That was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

In **serializer.py** Try:
`from rest_framework import serializers`

Django-rest framework doesn't have any API called serializer.

More: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Answer (score 1):

import should be
`from rest_framework import serializers`